# Asus U68 running DD-WRT

Tags: dd-wrt

I have a perplexing problem with my router I suspect. Long story short before we begin. Router was working great. Got a notice to update due to security issues. Updated firmware successfully. Was asked to log back in and got nothing but a blank page. Read on some forums that this was a problem with others who did the same firmware update. Okay, I've always wanted to try DD-WRT so did the DD-WRT flash to my router. All went well and all seems fine except for one odd thing.

I have a computer  that runs as a security camera program that is accessible from the Internet (web server) using noip.com . I can access the camera program from my computer at work and other places so I do have the port forwarding setup correctly. Here comes the odd part.....I am unable to access the web server from my other computers from my own house if they are hardwired. If I switch to wifi, all is well. I have a total of 5 computers at home and none are able to connect to the camera web server from my home. If I switch to wifi on my laptop, then all  is well (not all my computers have wifi). Any ideas. Thank you in advance.

Update. From any of my wired computers, I am able to access my camera computer by going directly to the IP of the computer (192.168.1.117) with no issues. I'm using Firefox but will try IE11 when I get home and update this post. I'll look at the IP addresses of both wired and wifi.

Comment: It sounds plausible that your DD-WRT setup might not being doing NAT loopback (a.k.a. hairpinning) correctly for Ethernet LAN clients. Especially if, within DD-WRT, the Ethernet LAN ports are not attached to the same virtual bridge interface as the Wi-Fi interfaces. Are your Ethernet LAN clients on a different IP subnet than your Wi-Fi clients?

Comment: Before doing anything, have you tried other web browsers so you can see the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is gone, and I'm able to access my webcam page using a wired connection now. Here's what I did, right, wrong or other.

1. Reset the router settings (DD-WRT) to the default setting.
2. Still not able to connect to my web server using wired connection, but noticed that when trying to connect to my web server, would end up at my router.
3. Looked for a setting in DD-WRT to change the default port (default is 80). No setting, but using a command was able to change it to 81.
4. Now I am able to connect to the webcam server using a wired connection.
5. I don't understand why when before I made any changes, was not directed to the router, but only "No connection available" and not prompted to log into the router.

All seems to be working well now. I'm sorry for taking up your time, but thank you for trying.